# How to get status code for every click in protractor using type script to verify the pages displayed after the click are not crashing like 400 code

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to click all the buttons,links on my web page but after clicking everything I need something to get status codes like:200 which is used to verify whether the displayed page after the click is not crashing with 404 or server error

Comment: This can be done like a web service testing.

Comment: Have a look into: https://github.com/marmelab/gremlins.js

Comment: This is not really what Protractor is designed for. Protractor works very well in simulating user actions on a website but typically users won't need check that status codes of requests. As Madhan suggested another type of testing may be more suitable for you. If you do want to go through the UI you could look into [cypress.io](https://www.cypress.io/) which allows you handle network requests more easily

Comment: Thanks for your input,but If I want to verify my page is showing yellow page or not how do I do that? like for ex: If I click on one link and its navigating to other page which is showing yellow page I tried validating it with 'expect to be and added the url   as '/url' but it is still showing test case as pass because I'm getting the expected url so I thought of handling it with status code..So can you suggest me if there is any other way that I can verify it without using status codes